# Raphael Paper when Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Splice is not working for array with an object and i am getting the following error. I am just reordering stuff based on the condition.

```
this.generatePartipant = function(userData,creatorID) {
    //arrange order based on order: owner, presenter and others
    var creatorObject;
    var ownerObject;
    for(var i=0;i < userData.length; i++){
        if(userData[i].senderId = creatorID)
            {
            creatorObject = jQuery.extend({},userData[i],{creator:true});
            userData.splice(i,1);
            }
        if(userData[i].senderId = whiteboardDesigner.user){
            ownerObject = jQuery.extend({},userData[i],{owner:true});
            userData.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    if(creatorObject != null){
        userData.push(creatorObject);
    }
    if (ownerObject != null){
        userData.push(ownerObject);
    }
}
```

**> error:**

```
            userData.splice(i,1);
Uncaught TypeError: Object [{"senderId":"9e61ec7e-8d7c-469d-88e5-38213dcb34f4","userName":"lkwerj","thumbnailId":null,"active":true,"camStarted":false,"micStarted":false,"imageUrl":null}] has no method 'splice'
```

Comment: First thing you might want to fix is you're using = assignment instead of equality == operation in the if statements.

Comment: @mkhatib oh i fixed it. Looks like the for loop lenght is showing 162. I am doing something wrong, can i use for loop there?

Comment: If it is an array you should be able to. Make sure userData is actually an array.

Comment: @mkhatib userData is like array but in this format [{object},{object}]